# Calculating no. of nodes in a Binary Tree in O(1)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, binary-tree

I am taking Data Structures and Algorithm course from Jovian. Currently on Binary Tress, but I am stuck on one question where we need to calculate no. of nodes in O(1) time.

Firstly here's how the final class `TreeMap` looks like:

```
class TreeMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        node = find(self.root, key)
        if not node:
            self.root = insert(self.root, key, value)
            self.root = balance_tree(self.root)
        else:
            update(self.root, key, value)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        node = find(self.root, key)
        return node.value if node else None
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return (x for x in list_all(self.root))
    
    def __len__(self):
        return size(self.root)
    
    def display(self):
        return display_keys(self.root):
```

Currently, it's calculating no. of nodes with the recursion method. I think we just need a counter and increment every time a node is created and we also have a hint to modify the `BSTNode` class. So this is how I did it:

```
class BSTNode:
    counter = 0
    
    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None
        BSTNode.counter += 1
```

But I don't know how do I implement or use the counter in `__len__` function in class TreeMap. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the link to Jovian Lesson: https://jovian.ai/learn/data-structures-and-algorithms-in-python/lesson/lesson-2-binary-search-trees-traversals-and-balancing

Comment: You can add a new property `self.len` to the `TreeMap` class which gets initialized in `__init__`, and every time you do `__setitem__` increment the `self.len` by 1. And in `__len__` you can just return value of `self.len`.

Comment: @Jay Hey thanks that worked. Also, can it be done with declaring counter in BSTNode class?

Comment: Yeah, as long as `BSTNode` is a global class object accessible within `TreeMap` you can return `BSTNode.counter` as the length, but its generally considered a bad pattern, you would be basically counting how many times a new `BSTNode` was created. What if you were to create two `TreeMap`s in your code?

Comment: @Jay Thanks, that clarifies things.